# How do I prevent Pop_OS! from changing the time zone when I'm connected over a VPN?

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, time-zone, pop-os

I'm running Pop_OS! and whenever I connect to a VPN it automatically changes the time zone to the time zone of the endpoint I'm connected to.

I want it to only update the time zone when I'm not connected to a VPN. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: So the time zone changes when you connect to the VPN so what happens when you disconnect from the VPN?

Comment: It changes back.

Comment: So you want the time zone to NOT change at all?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Pop but it's an Ubuntu derivative and so far using Gnome so but should be as simple as turning off "automatic date time".

Comment: I want the time zone to change when I physically change time zones, not when I connect and disconnect from a VPN.

Comment: Use a VPN server in your time zone.

Comment: I can't, because I need to connect to a VPN server for work.